# Using py2applet directly instead of setup.py py2app

Tags: python, macos, py2app

I am trying to create a py2app application on a Mac OS X 10.6 Server. I downloaded and installed py2app, but I can't get it to work (I get a "is a directory error"). The same exact code and setup.py file work perfectly with py2app on Mac OS X 10.9.

After some research I learned that Mac OS X 10.6 ships with py2applet and that's the one that works. I am trying to run py2applet directly to generate the app.

Here is my setup.py file:

```
from setuptools import setup

APP = ['app.py']
DATA_FILES = ['resource']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True, 'includes': ['wx', 'wx.wizard', 'wx.lib.mixins.listctrl']}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Here is the py2applet command that I am running:

It seems to complete, but the app crashes right away, so I feel like my parameters are wrong.

```
py2applet -i wx -i wx.wizard -i wx.lib.mixins.listctrl resource app.py
```

Thank you!